# Can't connect to MySQL server on '198.211.37.xx'

Tags: linux, mysql, centos5

For last couple of days I have tried many things to solve `Can't connect to MySQL server`. I would like to describe everything that I did so far.

1. Create a mysql user and GRANT ALL Privileges.
2. Bind 0.0.0.0 in `/etc/my.cnf`.
3. Change IP Tables like bellow:

   ```
   Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
   target     prot opt source               destination
   ACCEPT     tcp  --  127.0.0.0/8          anywhere
   Admin      tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:caiccipc
   REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:mysql reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:caiccipc reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssslic-mgr reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:h323hostcallsc reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:cadkey-tablet reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ufastro-instr reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:5062 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ca-2 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:5070 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:6060 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:8005 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:8009 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   REJECT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:itelserverport reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   ACCEPT     tcp  --  103.19.0.0/24        anywhere            tcp dpt:mysql state NEW,ESTABLISHED
   DROP       tcp  --  103.19.0.0/24        anywhere            tcp dpt:mysql state NEW,ESTABLISHED
   DROP       tcp  --  103.19.0.0/24        anywhere            tcp dpt:mysql
   ACCEPT     tcp  --  103.19.0.0/24        anywhere            tcp dpt:mysql
   ACCEPT     tcp  --  103.19.0.0/24        anywhere            tcp dpt:mysql state NEW,ESTABLISHED
   ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:mysql

   Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
   target     prot opt source               destination

   Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
   target     prot opt source               destination
   ```
4. My nmap for '198.211.37.xx' shows the bellow:

   ```
   PORT     STATE    SERVICE
   1/tcp    filtered tcpmux
   2/tcp    filtered compressnet
   3/tcp    filtered compressnet
   4/tcp    filtered unknown
   5/tcp    filtered rje
   6/tcp    filtered unknown
   7/tcp    filtered echo
   8/tcp    filtered unknown
   9/tcp    filtered discard
   10/tcp   filtered unknown
   11/tcp   filtered systat
   12/tcp   filtered unknown
   13/tcp   filtered daytime
   14/tcp   filtered unknown
   15/tcp   filtered netstat
   16/tcp   filtered unknown
   17/tcp   filtered qotd
   18/tcp   filtered msp
   19/tcp   filtered chargen
   21/tcp   open     ftp
   22/tcp   filtered ssh
   25/tcp   open     smtp
   26/tcp   open     unknown
   53/tcp   open     domain
   80/tcp   open     http
   110/tcp  open     pop3
   143/tcp  open     imap
   443/tcp  open     https
   465/tcp  open     smtps
   587/tcp  open     submission
   993/tcp  open     imaps
   995/tcp  open     pop3s
   3306/tcp open     mysql
   8080/tcp open     http-proxy
   ```

After doing all this still I am getting `Can't connect to MySQL server on '198.211.37.xx'` in my application.

I badly need expert suggestion on this issue.

Comment: What happens when you run `service mysqld status`?

Comment: @CraigWatson it shows  `mysqld (pid 7598) is running...`

Comment: I'am not A UNIX expert, but your REJECT rule "REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:mysql reject" does not take over your ALLOW rule ?

Comment: I'm also not entirely sure why you're rejecting that many ports. The most straightforward way of configuring iptables is to DENY all ports by default and allow only your own whitelisted set of ports/hosts.

Comment: The order of rules matter for iptables: the first matching rule wins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally strip all of your iptables configuration and start again, using [this documentation](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables) for reference.

For good practice, I would operate a "default deny" rule, and explicitly allow connections for the services you want to run (for example, ports 22 and 3306 for SSH and MySQL respectively). As per [this guide](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-4-block-all-incoming-traffic-but-allow-ssh.html) (bear in mind the commands may need to be altered for your system):

First, flush all existing rules:

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
```

Then, add default policies for the `INPUT`, `OUTPUT` and `FORWARD` chains, and allow loopback connections - note that this will allow all outbound access by default:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

Allow SSH (replace `<SERVER_IP>` with your server's public IP):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0.0.0.0/0 -d <SERVER_IP> --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Allow MySQL (replace `<OTHER_SERVER_IP>` with the IP address you want to whitelist MySQL access - I strongly suggest that you do this to avoid your MySQL port being world-visible). You can repeat the below for all ports that you want to be publicly accessible:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s <OTHER_SERVER_IP> -d <SERVER_IP> --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Finally, drop all other inbound traffic:

```
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```